# COMPOSER: choose the command line php you want to use. There is nothing there

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php

I'm using the Composer Windows installer and it brings me to this window,

[image]

There is nothing in the dropdown, but I'm not sure where to pick the correct command-line PHP. Should I direct it to the php.exe in XAMPP folder?

Comment: Click on browse button set php.exe file path.

Comment: if you are using xampp . see it under /xampp/php/php.exe . If are you using wampp it will be under /wamp/bin/php../php.exe

Comment: @BikashP thanks. Where is the composer.phar located? I need to install PHPCS but cmd can't find the composer.phar

Comment: Same folder php.exe located by default .

Comment: @BikashP there's none in /xampp/php/

Comment: search for composer.phar in your local mkachine .

Comment: @BikashP it's in C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin. What should I do now?

Comment: Copy composer.phar file and paste it to /xmpp/php folder . And you are done .

Comment: @BikashP, nah, stil lthe same. `Could not open input file: composer.phar`. I've copied everything in /ComposerSetup/bin.

Comment: For the ones using the wamp server the php.exe file location will be drive:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe

Comment: XAMPP with the PHP 5x branch uses the binary `php-win.exe` instead of `php.exe` which makes the Composer installer unable to run unless you also expect the person installing XAMPP to know how to remove and reinstall Windows services.

Comment: If you are using EasyPhp ?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you are using wampp do this:

1. Click the browser button.
2. Then select your file path like following path.

> (C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.exe)

If you are using xampp do this:

1. Click the browser button.
2. Then select your file path like the following path.

> (C:/xampp/php/php.exe)

Answer (score 9):

Yes you have to select php.exe from your xampp folder if you are using localhost.
choose this path...  xampp > php > php.exe

Comment: great answer @dinesh

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same screen. I'm using Vertrigo Server and all the things  that I have done was pick the php.exe file path by clicking on "Browse..." button (on my machine it is on C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\Php\php.exe). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:**

- Click **Browse Button**

**Step 2:**

- Go into **xampp > php**

**Step 3:**

- Select **php.exe**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ammps on Windows, you can click Browse -> 'C' -> Program Files -> Ammps -> 'Your PHP Version' -> php.exe, Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Composer automatically detects the directory in which your php.exe file is located.
mainly it is in C:\xampp\php directory if you are using Xampp server and C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.4.1 directory if using wamp server.
If your composer browser don't automatically detects the location of php.exe then you can use your browse option to locate it.